# Where can I find proof of work in the Bitcoin Core source code?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, mining-software

Does anyone knows which part of the Bitcoin Core [source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) contains the proof of work for mining, creating of block and adding to blockchain? What are the files and functions involved?

Answer (score 1):

The mining functionality that does background mining in the Bitcoin core was removed in August of 2016. See the following change log:

https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.13.0

The mining code itself is still available for testing and experimentation and is located in the files called "miner.cpp" and "miner.h" which are in the main src directory.